# express js multiple app middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple website with two independent applications (on same website, different routes), say profile app and a products app. I can make them routes, but I want to keep them in separate directory structure like apps. I wanted to know is it good practice to use one global.app or create separate app for each application?

Also, if I were to use separate apps, how can I have a common middleware between multiple apps?

Comment: These days, you would want to use the Router built into Express, and not make separate Express instances.  You can pass a Router into another Router.  It makes this sort of structure very convenient.

Comment: i read about router; can you gimme a example where two routers (in two phy directory structures) are using a common middleware for error handling?

Comment: The directory structure doesn't matter at all.  How you set up your directory structure is completely independent from how your application is structured.  You'll have one express app, and it will `app.use()` your two routers, and then `app.use()` the error handling middleware.

Comment: makes sense. thanks. What about `router.set("views", "jade")` as it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are attempting to do in expressjs is setup virtual host? It creates and instance of express and middleware that you can use in your main application.

Here is the [Github](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost).

Here is an example of Expressjs vhost

```
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');

/*
edit /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1       foo.example.com
127.0.0.1       bar.example.com
127.0.0.1       example.com
*/

// Main server app

var main = express();

// Vhost app

var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(vhost('*.example.com', redirect)); // Serves all subdomains via Redirect app
app.use(vhost('example.com', main)); // Serves top level domain via Main server app

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Express started on port 3000');
}
```

There are a few other packages out there. This site [here](http://shamadeh.com/blog/web/nodejs/express/2014/07/20/ExpressMultipleSites.html) goes into detail of how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two independent apps, my suggestion is to have two separate backends.  This is because you may, one day, want to move one to another server or upgrade it separately, etc.  Keeping the code separate from the get-go just formalizes the reality of the applications.

As for reusing middleware between the two applications, I would say don't do it.  If you have similar code between the two apps that you want to reuse, you can deploy that functionality as a sub-app.  This way, both apps reuse the same code but have different instances of that code.  If you want to learn how to build sub-apps, you can read up a tutorial I wrote on the topic (http://handyjs.org/article/your-guide-to-the-dark-arts-of-nodejs-sub-apps)